# I'm getting Error: Missing index on column(s). when I try to create a relationship between tables in phpMyAdmin Designer tool

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to create the database schema and include it in my software requirements specification for my school project, however, when I try to create a relationship between 2 tables, I get Error: Missing index on column(s).

Comment: make sure you created primary /unique keys

Comment: Every table of mine has a primary key ID.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think @HazarathChillara has this right; you need to create primary, unique, or index keys.

You said every table has an primary key, but did you make each foreign and referenced key an index as well? It sounds like you neglected to properly set up your table structure; I only get the error when I don't have a primary key or index on the particular columns I'm working with.

"[MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)"

You can just put an INDEX on the foreign key (often my referenced key is a primary key anyway, so I don't need any additional key on that column).

Answer (score 4):

This error appears only when you neglect table structure. Make sure that you Indexed a foreign key as well. you can see i marked how could i select my foreign key as index.[In this Image I am indexing selected, 'sr' my foreign key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBOzj.jpg)

Comment: Could you please edit your answer and provide a simple example on how indexes between two linked tables should look like

Answer (score 1):

As Usman Khan said you have to go to the structure tab of the particular table and clicked on more options and select 'INDEX' for the foreign key.
the below image will help you how to do it [image]

Answer (score -3):

I think i have another simple solve,
thing is, phpMyAdmin wont allow the addition of foreign keys to an already available data entry, so here is the my simple solve,

```
1. ensure to backup your database
2. confirm that your data was backed-up securely, recommended Offline backups
4. delete all data entries in all tables that will be part of the new relationship.
5. now Create the relevant relationships.
6. be sure you have created all required and preferred relations to avoid the need to 
    export data again
```

Comment: I don't think that deleting all data is good solution.